# Creating unique index - duplicate keys

Tags: sql-server, foreign-keys, primary-key

I'm trying to create a table from three queries (via UNION ALL) and I want to use one of the columns as a primary key, but I get an error message when doing so:

> "Msg 1505, Level 16, State 1, Line 31 The CREATE UNIQUE INDEX
>   statement terminated because a duplicate key was found for the object
>   name 'dbo.NEWTABLE' and the index name
>   'PK__NEWTABLE__B9388D2D25CFA66F'. The duplicate key value is
>   (AccountKey)."

I'm using the AdventureWorksDW2012 db and the key is used as a primary key in DimAccount, and a foreign key in FactFinance.

How do I get around this? I have to use the column I have tried to use as Primary key.

Comment: What do you mean by "create a table from three queries" - are you  making a new table and filling it from the queries? Or are you creating a view of those tables?

Answer (score 0):

Use UNION, not UNION ALL. If you have duplicates, UNION ALL will include them so it doesn't guarantee an unique key.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a unique index with `IGNORE_DUP_KEY` option. What it does is if it encounters a duplicate key it will discard the row in question without raising an error.

Check this sample:

```
create table #t (i int not null);

create unique index UQ on #t(i) with ignore_dup_key; 

insert #t values (1),(1),(2),(2);
```

Observe the messages:

```
Duplicate key was ignored.

(2 row(s) affected)
```

So, only two rows were inserted and only a warning raised.